# pymongo getting E11000 duplicate key error index pymongo error

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

So a little background, I've worked with MongoDB before in node.js with mongoose.js. And now I decided to try out to work with python and pymongo. But when I try to insert a document into my collection I just get an error off:

```
pymongo.errors.DuplicateKeyError: E11000 duplicate key error index: database.emails.$email_1 dup key: { : "mail@example.com" }
```

I have been looking around on the internet for a solution both in python but also in other languages. It might very well be that sense iv only used mongoose.js to talk to mongo before and that I might not fully grasp the basics off MongoDB.

From model.py

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

class Model(object):
    client = MongoClient()
    db = client["database"]
    collection_name = ""

    def __init__(self):
        self.collection = self.db[self.collection_name]

    def save(self, data):
        self.collection.insert_one(data)
```

From Post.py

```
from model import Model

class Post(Model):

    collection_name = "emails"

    def __init__(self):
        super(Post, self).__init__()
```

And in app.py I just do

```
from models.Post import Post

post = Post()
post.save({"email":"mail@example.com", "name":"bob"})
```

When there is no document in the database it inserts fine. But if I try to insert the same again I get the DuplicateKeyError. It is as if MongoDB expects all the fields to have a unique or am I misunderstanding the processes?

Im using the latest version of pymongo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> pymongo.errors.DuplicateKeyError: E11000 duplicate key error index: database.emails.$email_1 dup key: { : "mail@example.com" }

Judging by the error, you actually have a unique index defined for the `email` field.

FYI, you can get the index information using [`index_information()`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.index_information) method:

```
self.collection.index_information()
```

Comment: So how wuld i make it so the email or any other field is not a unique index?

Comment: @magra RTFM: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/#options