# Python mongodb error with email as unique key

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, unique-index

I have a collection with Username, Password and Email, so I created a unique index with pymongo in python :

```py
import pymongo 

info.create_index( [("Username", pymongo.TEXT), ("Email", pymongo.TEXT)],unique=True)
```

first insert:

```
mydict = { "Username": "userA","Email": "emailA@example.com"}
mycol.insert_one(mydict)
```

second insert:

```
mydict = { "Username": "userB","Email": "emailB@example.com"}
mycol.insert_one(mydict)
```

But when I test it with a second insert it throws this exception:

```
pymongo.errors.DuplicateKeyError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: users.info index: Username_text_Email_text dup key: { : "com", : 0.6666666666666666 }
```

am I missing something here?

Comment: I think this is similiar question of https://stackoverflow.com/q/36649794/4711785

Comment: What were your two inserts? Were they the same username+email combination? If so, then this behavior is expected as the combination of username+email must be unique for every document in that collection. If a write would cause a collision, then an exception will be thrown as you've seen here. If you don't want your program to crash, then be sure to wrap your insert in a try/catch block and handle the exception accordingly.

Comment: @B. Fleming sorry that I wasn't clear, my first insert was for example Username: userA and Email: EmailA@example.com , when i insert Username: userB and Email:EmailB@example.com it throws that exception

Comment: I would recommend checking to see if that user currently exists and go from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with your index creation on `email` field. After looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52442828/5030709) SO Post, you need to create the `email` index with `pymongo.ASCENDING` option instead of `pymongo.TEXT`.

So, it will be something like this.

```
info.create_index( [("Username", pymongo.TEXT), ("Email", pymongo.ASCENDING)],unique=True)
```

Also, it is always better to `clear` the dict object before reusing it since pymongo is adding `_id` field to the document before inserting it and might cause unnecessary conflict issues.

```
mydict = { "Username": "userA","Email": "emailA@example.com"}
mycol.insert_one(mydict)
<pymongo.results.InsertOneResult object at 0x1086c7bc8>
mydict
{'Username': 'userA', 'Email': 'emailA@example.com', '_id': ObjectId('5d5dfd90337d3d79a9bf1da8')}
mydict.clear()
mydict = { "Username": "userB","Email": "emailB@example.com"}
mycol.insert_one(mydict)
<pymongo.results.InsertOneResult object at 0x1086c7e48>
```

---

**Update -**

When you create one single compound index with both fields(given in your question) and asking uniqueness, you are asking that the combination of both fields data should always be unique(not the individual fields data).

So, according to mongo, below inserts are valid and not duplicate since combination is unique.

> { "Username": "userA","Email": "emailA@example.com"}
>  { "Username":
>   "userB","Email": "emailA@example.com"}

If your requirement is that UserName should not repeat more than once and Email field should not repeat more than once then separate individual indexes are fine(given in your answer).

First, get your requirement correct then create the indexes accordingly. Also, your answer has indexes not created with `pymongo.TEXT` option and that's why you were able make 2 inserts with different email but if you create the Email index with TEXT option then you won't be able to insert emailA & emailB.

Here is SO POST which will give little bit idea on difference between TEXT indexes vs Normal Indexes.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24316510/5030709

Comment: I tried this solution but somehow monogodb keeps adding the duplicate values... "Username" works fine but something wrong with "Email"

Comment: Can you provide your inserts where duplicate data is being inserted?

Comment: for example if my first insert is : mydict = { "Username": "userA","Email": "emailA@example.com"} and my second insert is : mydict = { "Username": "userB","Email": "emailA@example.com"} it will be stored

Comment: @M.omer check my updated answer. It kind of feels like your requirement has changed after your initial question.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I solved it (Don't know why it works... But it works):

I changed index creation:
Instead of:

```py
import pymongo 

info.create_index( [("Username", pymongo.TEXT), ("Email", pymongo.TEXT)],unique=True)
```

I did:

```py
import pymongo

mycol.create_index( "Username",unique=True)
mycol.create_index( "Email",unique=True)
```

if someone know why it works.. enlighten me please :)

Comment: Ok well that's 2 seperate unique indexes which may be fine for what you need. If you ever get "the first works but the second doesn't" with mongodb indexes, then almost certainly your fields don't match your keys. The first works because it is effectively "blank" and the second fails because you can't have a duplicate blank.